# Getting a FieldLookupValue from Sharepoint in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

Looking on the net I came up with this 2 functions to request Sharepoint using this 3 DLL with powershell :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

This function is used to get all items from a list

```
Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $items
}
```

And this one to work the list :

```
Function getChangeListsFromSharepoint(){
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $items = Get-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle $listName 
    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        /** Working HERE **/
    }
    $context.Dispose()
}
```

Now when I'm displaying all item content using `Write-Host $item.Fields` I've got something like this :

```
[Title,"blabla"]
...
[SpecialField,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]]
[OtherField,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue]
```

I'm trying to get the value of SpecialField and OtherField. To do so I'm using `$item["SpecialField"].LookupValue`. And I've got no problem. But when I'm doing it on `OtherField` the value is empty. If I try to use `$item["OtherField"].LookupID` the value is not empty and I've got an ID. How can I get the value behind this ID ? What's the difference between `FieldLookupValue[]` and `FieldLookupValue` ?

Comment: Isn't there a [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: AFAIK, there are lazy loaded properties. Maybe you have to request the value on yourself using it's ID?

Comment: Not sure if it's belong to SharePoint Stack since it's written in PowerShell.
How can I request them with the ID ? FYI the ID is the position of the item inside the list he's from. OtherField is a list of 13 elements so the ID is between 1 and 13.

Comment: PowerShell is a well known Management Tool for SharePoint, not only a programming language ;) Ask yourself: Would it make any difference, if written in any other language? But yeah, it's not totally unrelated to SO ;)
I don't know. If I would, I had posted an answer

Comment: I think I might have found out the problem : the FieldChoice is made from another list on the same site. And the user I'm using isn't allowed to access this list. That's why I'm not able to request the Value but I still get the ID. I'm requesting the rights and then I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was easy : my user didn't had the rights to explore the (field)list because it was from a (sharepoint)list on wich he didn't had any rights. What is strange is that on the website the value was visible but it's not when using powershell.

Answer (score 2):

`FieldLookupValue[]` is a multi-value lookup column.

It has property `Allow multiple values` set to true and contains an array of items.

[image]

So, `$item["OtherField"].LookupValue` will not work here, you need to iterate it over as below:

```
#multi-value lookup
$mvLookup = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[]] $item["OtherField"]        

$mvLookup |% { "Lookup Value: $($_.LookupId):$($_.LookupValue)" }
```

which results in values as below:

[image]

`FieldLookupValue` is a single value lookup column. It has the `Allow multiple values` set to false and contains a single item. So, `$item["SpecialField"].LookupValue` will work here

Comment: You've got the wrong way : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[].LookupValue => Working. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue.LookupValue => Not Working

Comment: That's quite strange, I tested the code it working and provides me value. I have only a single item in list and it has column of type multi-value. So, i retrieved it that way.

Comment: I'm just getting the ID inside the list. (Like I've got 4 choices so the ID will be between 1 and 4). i can hard code the list and the value in powershell but I'd like to be more dynamic. Maybe I can query this specific list and get the value using the ID but I've not idea how to.

Comment: For information : the fieldType on sharepoint is a SPFieldChoice. If it helps.

Comment: I think I might have found out the problem : the FieldChoice is made from another list on the same site. And the user I'm using isn't allowed to access this list. That's why I'm not able to request the Value but I still get the ID.